# Getting the ErrorMessage Bag in Laravel Validation during Validation

Tags: php, laravel, validation

As the question states. I am using the validation method where the Rules and Custom Messages are placed in the Http/Requests folder. However, I want to get the messageErrorBag in Laravel I don't have any problems if I am using the code below I can easily add my own variables to be passed together with the validator message bag.

```
$validatedData = $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
        'body' => 'required',
    ]);
```

However, if using the code below. I cannot do it since Laravel already handles the error return as per documentation.

```
public function store(StoreBlogPost $request)
{
    // The incoming request is valid...

    // Retrieve the validated input data...
    $validated = $request->validated();
}
```

My question how can I do it? before it redirects back with the error message bag.? Is it possible

Answer (score 0):

If you use StoreBlogPost in Controller , it automatically returns messages but if you want your messages in body of controller you should add validator to your controller body and use this code:

```
if ($validator->fails())
{
  foreach ($validator->messages()->getMessages() as $field_name => $messages)
  {
    var_dump($messages); // messages are retrieved (publicly)
  }

}
```

hope it helps